# How to correctly parse complex viewmodel to separate domain models in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I wonder how could I solve the following case : there are a form on website where manager input very big amount of data to Viewmodel and pass to server-side.

```
class CitizenRegistrationViewModel { 
     public string NationalPassportId { get;set; }
     public string Name { get;set; }
     public List<string> PreviousRegisteredOfficeCodes {get;set;}
     // about 30 fields like strings, Booleans, HttpBasedFiles (pdf,jpg).
}
```

And the problem that in domain this data need to be logically separated and stored in different tables (classes in EF) like **CitizensNationalPassportsTable**, **CitizensWorkingPlaceRecordsTable**, etc. There are **no** complex class Citizen with properties like :

```
public class Citizen {
    public ICollection<CitizensWorkingPlaceRecords> workingPlaces
    // etc...
}
```

but this properties are separately stored in different tables with **no** one-to-one or one-to-many relations (no **FK** here) . The only **NationalPassportId** property could be used as navigation key (unique per user and all records related to user in different tables contains this key).

Should I write big amount of code to parse Viewmodel to domains models like :

```
public void CitizenRegistrationViewModelToDomainModel(CitizenRegistrationViewModel model){
    CitizenNationalPassport passport = new CitizenNationalPassport(model.NationalPassportId);
    CitizensWorkingPlaceRecord workplace = new CitizensWorkingPlaceRecord(model.PreviousRegisteredOfficeCodes, model.NationalPassportId);
     // 12 extra objects need to create...
    db.CitizenNationalPassports.Add(passport);

}
```

Or is there any more correct approach to handle this problem? I wanted to use AutoMapper, but is it the best solution? 
I can't change business models' logic, as it is a legacy project.

Comment: how to retrieve your data from the server ? I mean EF queries ?

Comment: @Sampath, previous team implemented it in a very simple\stupid way : collecting all required data by var someClassObject = db.SomeTable_1.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.NationalPassportId); Then compose all retrieved objects into single viewmodel.

Comment: OK,now can you tell me what do you need to do ? For me it's not clear..

Comment: IMO Automapper isn't worth using.  It really only helps you if the view models and domain models are practically the same -- which probably indicates that your view models or domain models aren't really optimal in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a set of classes that represents the data that the browser is exchanging with ASP.NET MVC. Let's name them for example, Input Models. In this classes you have metadata attributes, custom properties and many things that are relates with the exchange between browser and web server.

You should have another set of classes that represent your database structure, those are your Entity Framework POCO classes. Let's name them DB Models. It does not matter how POCO and fancy they are, they always map to tables and columns, so they are always tight to the DB structure.

You should have another set of classes that are your domain classes, the classes you use when operating objects in your business layer.These are binding/persistence/representation agnostic.

You should have a repository that knows how to persist a domain entity. In your case it will be a class that knows how to operate the DB models and the DbContext.

1. Then, when you get input from your browser, you bind that data to the input models and those are passed to the controller (this is done automatically by the `DefaultModelBinder` or you can use your own `IModelBinder`).
2. When you get an input model, you have to create a new domain entity using that data (in case that is an actual new entity). Once you have your domain object ready, you pass it to the repository to be saved.
3. The repository is responsible of knowing how to save the domain entity in the database, using the DB models.

In essence, the Controller or the business service instance you operate in the Controller's action context should be responsible of articulate the interaction between these elements without them knowing each others.

Answer (score 1):

AutoMapper or an alternative could be used to automate the mapping from View model to Domain models, but this only makes sense if properties are named identical in View and Domain models. If this is not the case you'll end up writing mapping rules which doesn't help you. It just moves code from your current mapping classes to the AutoMapper configuration. So, if you're in a position to modify your viewmodels I'd go for AutoMapper or anything similar, if not I'd use what you currently have.